# Fragment backstack with tab fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have Parent fragment which contains 2 tab fragment.

1. ParentFragmet
2. TabFragment1
3. TabFragment2
4. NewFragment

Now from the TabFragment1 on button click open new Fragment. 
From the newFragment i select the values and click on a button calling a

```
(activity as MainActivity).supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
```

And one Interface method which refresh the view

```
 tabFrag1InterFace?.onRefresh(MyValue)
```

Now on TabFragment1 Ovverride the OnRefresh method and its calling proper.

```
TabFragment1

override fun onRefresh(myValue) {
    Log.i(TAG,"TabFragment1 onRefresh Before postDelay")
    Handler().postDelayed({
        Log.i(TAG,"TabFragment1 onRefresh after postDelay")
    }, 3000)
}
```

But when i use the newFragment value and set in the textview, value not updated.

I was facing this same issue in normal fragment but while i add the postDelay in normal fragment it work like charm, but the same will not work in Tab fragments.

When i debug the whole process
I popback call
The ParentFragment onResume call and redirect to default TabFragment1 and also its calling interface `OnRefresh()` method.

The log i have get as below.

```
10-11 15:35:16.710 10208-10208/com.app I/TabFragment1: TabFragment1 clicked for NewFragment
10-11 15:35:16.783 10208-10208/com.app I/NewFragment: NewFragment onCreateView
10-11 15:35:48.440 10208-10208/com.app I/NewFragment: NewFragment popBackStack(Clicked submit)
10-11 15:35:48.453 10208-10208/com.app I/TabFragment1: TabFragment1 onRefresh Before postDelay
10-11 15:35:48.488 10208-10208/com.app I/ParentFragent: Called Parent Frag onCreateView
10-11 15:35:48.538 10208-10208/com.app I/ParentFragent: Navigate to TabFragment1 from Parent Frag
10-11 15:35:48.760 10208-10208/com.app I/ParentFragent: Called Parent Frag OnResume
10-11 15:35:51.467 10208-10208/com.app I/TabFragment1: TabFragment1 onRefresh after postDelay
```

Please help Any way to refresh the view because i have to display the data which selected from the NewFragment.

Comment: I would suggest you to open a new activity when you click the button in your first framgent. Don't do too much of nesting with framgents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, foFragment).addToBackStack(null)
    .commit()
```

Replace with

```
supportFragmentManager
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.content_frame, foFragment).addToBackStack(null)
    .commit()
```